# Getting error after running "make watch" during babel setup

Tags: makefile, babeljs

I am having a problem with babel setup on Windows: I navigated to babel repo and ran make watch  (I didn't run make bootstrap because I have already run it some days ago) and I get the following error:

```
C:\Users\Lenovo\Desktop\babel\babel>make watch

rm -rf  packages/*/test/tmp
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, rm -rf packages/*/test/tmp, ...) failed.
make (e=2): The system cannot find the file specified.
make: *** [Makefile:140: test-clean] Error 2

C:\Users\Lenovo\Desktop\babel\babel>
```

Maybe is it because make is not properly installed?

Comment: Looks more like babel hasn't been built before, causing the clean-up rule to fail, which for some reason is a prerequisite to watch. I'd try build other targets like `make build` and try `make watch` right after. File a bug on babel while you're at it.

Comment: Please don't post screenshots to StackOverflow.  Instead, cut and paste the text into the question and use formatting to ensure it is treated as code and not wrapped, etc.  Screenshots can't be copied, they can't be searched, etc.

Comment: The problem here is not that things haven't been built before.  The `-f` option to the `rm` command means that it will not fail if the file to be removed doesn't exist. The problem is that this makefile is using the POSIX system (for example GNU/Linux or MacOS) command `rm` and you're running on a Windows system where they use different commands. Either this package cannot be built on Windows at all, or it requires a POSIX emulation layer to be installed and used to build the software.  Or, there's some option somewhere you have to set to tell it to build for Windows.